# Snowpark Java | Scala Signature package has wrong version

Tags: java, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

A while back, I created a Java project using sbt build tool.

Sample:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.11"

crossPaths := false

javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "11")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.junit.jupiter" % "junit-jupiter-api" % "5.10.1" % Test,
  "org.junit.jupiter" % "junit-jupiter-engine" % "5.10.1" % Test,
  "net.aichler" % "jupiter-interface" % JupiterKeys.jupiterVersion.value % Test,
  "com.snowflake" % "snowpark" % "1.8.0" % "provided",
  "eu.bitwalker" % "UserAgentUtils" % "1.21"
)
Compile / unmanagedClasspath ++= update.value.select(configurationFilter("compileonly"))
autoScalaLibrary := false
```

With this configuration, I was able successfully connect to Snowflake and test my Java procedure handlers.

To my surprise, it suddenly started failing today. I do not know about `sbt` or Scala and don't have clue what went wrong.
This is the error I am getting from `Snowpark` library -

```
java.io.IOException: Scala signature package has wrong version
 expected: 5.0
 found: 5.2 in scala.collection.immutable.package
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.checkVersion(UnPickler.scala:124)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.<init>(UnPickler.scala:66)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler.unpickle(UnPickler.scala:47)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.unpickleClass(JavaMirrors.scala:660)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.SymbolLoaders$TopClassCompleter.$anonfun$complete$2(SymbolLoaders.scala:37)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.slowButSafeEnteringPhaseNotLaterThan(SymbolTable.scala:332)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.SymbolLoaders$TopClassCompleter.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:34)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.completeInfo(Symbols.scala:1551)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1514)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$13.scala$reflect$runtime$SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$super$info(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:221)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol.$anonfun$info$1(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:158)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol.info(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:149)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol.info$(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:158)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$13.info(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:221)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.openPackageModule(SymbolTable.scala:355)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.openPackageModule(SymbolTable.scala:410)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.SymbolLoaders$LazyPackageType.$anonfun$complete$3(SymbolLoaders.scala:83)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.slowButSafeEnteringPhaseNotLaterThan(SymbolTable.scala:332)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.SymbolLoaders$LazyPackageType.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:80)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.completeInfo(Symbols.scala:1551)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1514)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$9.scala$reflect$runtime$SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$super$info(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:209)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol.$anonfun$info$1(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:158)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol.info(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:149)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol.info$(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:158)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$9.info(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:209)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef.baseClasses(Types.scala:2280)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.FindMembers$FindMemberBase.init(FindMembers.scala:36)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.FindMembers$FindMember.init(FindMembers.scala:257)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.$anonfun$findMember$1(Types.scala:1042)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.findMemberInternal$1(Types.scala:1041)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.findMember(Types.scala:1046)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.memberBasedOnName(Types.scala:672)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.member(Types.scala:636)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getRequiredClass(Mirrors.scala:55)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.requiredClass(Mirrors.scala:121)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ConsClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:465)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ConsClass(Definitions.scala:465)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverseForce.force(JavaUniverseForce.scala:286)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverseForce.force$(JavaUniverseForce.scala:18)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse.force(JavaUniverse.scala:30)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse.init(JavaUniverse.scala:162)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse.<init>(JavaUniverse.scala:93)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.package$.universe$lzycompute(package.scala:29)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.package$.universe(package.scala:29)
    at com.snowflake.snowpark.functions$.lit(functions.scala:148)
    at com.snowflake.snowpark.functions.lit(functions.scala)
    at com.snowflake.snowpark_java.Functions.lit(Functions.java:82)
```

Any leads would be appreciated?

Update: Looks like it is failing for a very specific scenario, a simple snowpark program is still working.